# The issue of white edges in rounded corners in Android

Tags: android

In Android, the view with a transparent background (# C20B0C0E) is overlaid with a white background view (# C6D1DC), and the overall rounded corners are cropped with white edges

How to solve this problem？

android 10  SDKVersion 30